# Powerpoint Macro won't run on 64bit Powerpoint

Tags: powerpoint, office-addins, powerpoint-addins

Complete novice with Powerpoint addins/macros. Inherited this Macro which the staff use and is a pain since it only works on 32bit office and we are trying to standadise using 64bit office.
What would be the steps for me to allow this add in to work on 64bit office?
The add in I believe is just used to resize images so when they create powerpoints they can be uniform and follow a format.

Here is  a link to the add in - https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1QztUJSblsUWrrF2NtF_BVDF74DJpz16k/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106395195857954450494&rtpof=true&sd=true

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know how many people will be willing to load an add-in unseen from an unknown source. You'll get more help if you edit your question to include your source code if it's not insanely long. Otherwise, copy/paste it into a text file and include a link to that.  Almost certainly the problem is that you'll need to rewrite the bits that DIM variables to make things 32- and 64-bit compatible.  Whisper this to Google for some useful references:  64-bit vs 32-bit vba

Comment: Incidentally, I already have a free add-in called THOR, that lets the user select and "memorize" the size/position of any shape, then apply the same size/position to any other shape or shapes. 32- and 64-bit compatible. 
 https://pptools.com/free/FAQ00002-THOR-The-Hammer.htm

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Yes I did think this after I posted the question! How do I go about getting the source code? I literally just have access to the PPT add in file which is linked in the google drive. Can I just open it with a text editor and paste it in? It seems the text file is pretty long when I do this. Can I use some kind of program to convert the file add in back to source code?

Thanks for the suggestion with the Thor add-in but users are quite accustomed to this custom add-in as it is set up specifically for their presentation standard.

Comment: It depends on what type of file you actually have. If it's a PPT or PPTM, you can open it, press F11 to go to the VBA editor and open the project on the left. As long as the code isn't password protected, you can see/edit it. If it's protected, you'll need to know the password in order to open it.

If all you have is an add-in file (PPA or PPAM) you'll need to modify the registry first. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129362/powerpoint-2007-2010-vba-ppam-add-in-does-not-show-up-in-vba-editor-when-open 

If you have a Mac, better find a PC or go bald. ;-)

Comment: @SteveRindsberg seems like its Password protected so I think that's the end of that unless you know a way to remove passwords? 

Comment: There are ways to remove passwords, but it's considered bad form to offer password cracking help. A bit of googling should lead you to something workable.